# Rails user profile devise :has_many or :has_many_through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations, model-associations, rails-models

I'm wracking my brain about how to start setting up the following set of model relationships in my project. I'm not looking for the complete solution (models, tables, migrations, etc), just a little help to get me going in the right direction. I learn more by struggling on my own :)

In short, I want my `Users` (created with Devise) to have a set of `Inclinations` that represent preferences they have to certain things (i.e. warmer weather vs colder weather, watching sports vs playing sports, etc) on a sliding scale (coded 5 to -5, zero excluded). Each `Inclination` (or `InclinationData`?) will be in a separate table with a name, description, etc, and all `Inclinations` will get their data pulled from that table (so I don't repeat myself throughout my application). Also, every `User` will have one `Inclination` record for each `InclinationData(?)` by default.

As for the setup, will I need:

- 5 tables (3 main ones and two join tables)?
- Just three (main three models)?
- Four (main three models & a joining table for `Inclinations` and `InclinationData`)?
- Four (main three models & a joining table for `Users` & `Inclinations`)?
- Perhaps something simpler like a single `Profile` or `Preferences` model that's bound to a `User`?

I can never figure out how to decide if joining tables are necessary, and this is the most complex association I've ever tried.

I appreciate any help, and please let me know if you need more information to be able to help me out.

Comment: What is the difference between the models Inclination and InclinationData?

Comment: Each user will have `Inclination`, the actual record of their rating, timestamps, etc. Since every user will have the same set of `Inclinations`, I wanted to pull the information (name, description, etc) from a different table & link it to the `Inclination` somehow. That's why I was wondering about how many tables I needed. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say, all `Users` have the same set of `Inclinations`. You can put the description of the `Inclinations` in one model/table and the users ratings in the joining table `UserInclination` , according to eabraham:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_inclinations
  has_many :inclinations, through: :users_inclinations

end

class UsersInclination < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :inclinations

  attr_accessible :user_id, :inclination_id, preference_score
end

class Inclination < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users_inclinations

   attr_accessible :description, :name, :low_label, :high_label
end
```

So you can pull the description (i.e. to build the rating form) from `Inclinations` and store the individual ratings with

```
an_inclination= Inclination.find_by_name('weather')
user.user_inclination.create(inclination: an_inclination, preference_score: the_users_score)
```

Comment: THAT is awesome! I like how your solution even includes labels for the high and low ends of the range. Exactly what I needed & didn't even ask for. Marked as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've reasoned through your request:

Users has_many UserInclinations and Inclinations has_one UserInclinations. Roughly, the models should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_inclinations

  #default Devise attr_accessible
end

class UserInclinations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :inclinations

  attr_accessible :user_id, :inclination_id, preference_score
end

class Inclination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_inclination

  attr_accessible :preference
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it definitely gets me closer. The part that was confusing was what I mentioned in my comment to you above. Each user will have the same set of `Inclinations`, and I'm trying to find a DRY way to accomplish this.

Comment: So in my example above, the fixed set of inclinations are stored in the inclination table. The UserInclinations table records the preference score for each user's inclination.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was overcomplicating it bigtime! Let me have a go at it and I'll see what I can do. Thanks!